# Are there any conventions for graphically describe how software works to user?

Tags: architecture, uml, modeling

I'm not asking for UML, UML is mainly for software architects, programmers and integration specialists. 
I'm asking if there are any conventional ways to describe software to users, for example an administrator?

Imagine a complex software package that incorporates many modules, small subprograms, database engine etc. How to describe module dependencies, how submodules work and what they do without going deep into implementation details?

Comment: You might want to check the reply as an answer or explain what more's missing. I have some good info on the subject but can't post it because the question is closed. And I don't dare to edit an unchecked answer. So either reopen the question (shouldn't be closed in the first place, in my opinion) or check the current reply as an answer.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson I checked the answer, I'm looking forward to hearing from you. I suspected that this question can be closed because similar question were. I also thing it shouldn't be closed but I don't have enough strength to argue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually pull out the default symbols of Visio. DB are very commonly depicted by a yellow can and there are a few others very widely spread one. However, I'm not sure there's a defined convention and definitely not one that covers the more quirky aspects.

IMHO, if you get the audience to understand what you mean, you've succeeded.